# Session not reachable in object?

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I got this failure:

> Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION

in this code:

```
<?php

session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION, $_SESSION['foo'] = uniqid());

// and

namespace Some\Deep\Namespace;

class Session
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        var_dump($_SESSION);
    }
}
```

This seems very strange because I always thought it is superglobal like PHP said:

> Note: This is a 'superglobal', or automatic global, variable.

So what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need add something like this?
`$newClass = new Session();`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't inilize the class so inilize it like this

```
$session = new Session();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for this. 
I got an instance of this class.
Due to this damn complex framework, I didn't see that they put some included files even before the bootstrap / session_start.